# What does “two-by-six crashing" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-usage

Recently I came across a phrase, “two-by-six crashing” in the following paragraph in Dan Brown’s fiction, “Inferno”:

> "Langdon had feared as much; the last thing they needed now was to
>   send a **two-by-six** crashing through a Vasari canvas – P.265"

I know the word, “two-by-four” as a finished wood used for building that measures two inches wide and four inches deep, but I’m new to “two-by-six (crashing, explosion, shock, impact).”

Google provides a sequence of headings of “two-by-six” as a quote from Dan Brown’s “Inferno” without any definition or meaning of the phrase.

Google N-Gram shows that the phrase has existed since 1820’s. The usage peaked during 1900 to 1920, and is dwindling off to 0.000.000.20% incidence level today.

It seems to me the phrase means an enormous impact, but I’m not sure.
What does “two-by-six” something mean? Is that usage coming back to life?

Comment: I'm kinda confused that you fully understand what "two-by-four" means but can't infer that two-by-six is a slightly different size of the same thing.

Comment: @David Richerby 2-by-4 became a Japanee word, but  my only association with the word is the wooden materials used for a house because there are many house builders that make "two-by-four" construction  their selling point against conventional method of building wooden houses in our country.

Answer (score 65):

As the other answers have noted, "a two-by-six" should be interpreted the same way as "a two-by-four", just a slightly larger version; it refers to a particular size of cut lumber.

Your confusion seems to come from mis-parsing the grammar of the sentence. You may be misinterpreting "**crashing**" as a noun that is being modified by "*two-by-six*", analogously to the sentence "I would send a *large* **envelope** through the mail."

However, in this sentence, "**crashing**" is a participle modifying "*two-by-six*", describing the manner in which it would go through the canvas (violently). It should be parsed analogously to the sentences "I will send a *ball* **flying** through the air" or "He sent the *child* **laughing** from the room." On its own, "two-by-six crashing" is not a phrase with any particular meaning.

An alternate way to phrase the sentence might be, "the last thing they needed now was to cause a two-by-six board to crash through a Vasari canvas."

Comment: +1 This seems to be where the key misunderstanding comes from, and is the key answer. On it's own "two-by-six crashing" is an out of context sentence fragment

Answer (score 15):

A two-by-six is a board that’s just like a two-by-four — except that it’s wider. :)

There are other [measures of lumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumber#North_American_softwoods) like this, such as a four-by-four. All of them are industry-specific terms that do not measure out to the exact size their nominal dimensions might otherwise lead you to wrongly infer.

[image: North American lumber dimensions]

This is because they were originally the dimensions used for *green, unfinished* lumber, and the subsequent finishing necessarily trimmed a bit from them. Nonetheless, the exact dimensions listed above are the actual ones that people require and expect. It’s just too awkward to adjust the language to funny fractions.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Here in NZ a 2x4 is 45x90. Seems like it would be annoying not having them in a 1:2 ratio.

Comment: Though 4x4 (four-by-four) usually means four-wheel drive.

Comment: Australia has a similar method of categorising lumber but we put the larger dimension first: four-by-two (usually pronounced “four-be-two”, perhaps reflecting a predominance of Irish convicts in our country’s nascent building trade). It’s the standard cross-section for constructing a wall frame.

Answer (score 4):

Hitting something with a 2x6 piece of lumber does more damage than hitting something with a 2x4 piece of lumber-- although maybe not exactly 1.5 times as much.

> Hit me with a two by four

is a fairly common expression.  According to our own @RegDwigHt in his answer to the ELU question [What does "hit me like a two-by-four" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9373/what-does-hit-me-like-a-two-by-four-mean)

it means

> ..... that the observation was a big surprise or a great shock; an aha
>   experience or a eureka moment; an eye-opener.

@BorroO says

> "It hit me like a two-by-four" means that you've been hit pretty hard

@mickyf says:

> This may have derived from the story about how to handle Mules.
>   "First" (clobbering mule with 2x4), "you have to get their attention."

All these answers were given before references were mandatory.  Being hit by a two by four is such a common expression that I am not going to give a reference, but I will give a reference for getting the mule's attention.  See [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/management-rewired/201005/changing-the-mind-the-mule), *Changing the Mind of the Mule
Why don't two-by-fours work as a management tool?*

Dan Brown was referring to a [Vasari canvas print](https://fineartamerica.com/shop/canvas+prints/giorgio+vasari), a piece of wall art,  upon which a  well-wielded two by six would inflict a great deal of damage.

Comment: Maybe not 1.5× as much, but how ’bout ¹⁴⁰⁄₈₉× as much? :-)

Comment: I think if the movie is to go by, it is a piece of ceiling art, that they aren't keen to destroy by dropping anything, including themselves or a piece of wood, through it.

Answer (score 2):

We call them "six-by-two" in New Zealand. It's a piece of wood that's common here.